# Running another file in C

Tags: c

I'm making a program, and it's supposed to run a file in a different directory (/files/runme.c). How can I run this file in C?

I have tried the `system()` function, however this does not work.

**MAIN.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
 system("runme.c");
 return 0;
}
```

**runme.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int runme() {
 printf("hello world");
}
```

My expected result is:

> hello world

I get:

> exit status -1

I want it to run everything inside the contents of runme.c. How can I do this (on Windows and Linux)?

Comment: The `.c` files do not *run*. They have to be compiled into executable first.

Comment: you have to compile the code in runme.c and then execute the generated binary. what you're trying is equivalent to trying to execute a txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `runme()` function from a different file to be passed to your main , you need to create a header file with the prototype of the `runme()` function in it, include this header file in main.c and compile using both files.

main.h:

```
int runme(void);
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h" //main.h needs to be in the same directory as main.c

int main(void) {
   runme();
   return 0;
}
```

runme.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int runme() {
   printf("hello world");
}
```

Finally compile:

gcc main.c {path}/runme.c

Comment: Good answer, but I think it makes more sense to call the header file "runme.h" instead of "main.h", since it is the header file that defines the interface of "runme.c".

Comment: indeed that's better.

Answer (score 1):

from system() you can run .exe
as far as I know not .c.
Just compile the .c file you want to run put it on same folder as of file containing the main()
eg.
second_program.c->compiled->copy the generated .exe file to the same folder and then use the system(second_program.exe)

or you have to create two file second_program.h for header files and functions prototype etc
and second_program.c for their definition  and then use include  
if the files are not in the same folder as of main()
then you have to add the location of second_program in your program properties 
or add include "second_program.h" if files exist in same folder